Referenced collection field returned null in result
I have this Mongoose aggregate that returns the right records but do not include fields in the lookup collection i.e referenced collection.
These are my schemas:
const bonded_terminal_schema = mongoose.Schema({    
    fullname: {
        type: String,
        required: true,                     
    },   
    email: {
        type: String,        
        required: false,                  
    },       
    phone: {
        type: String, 
        required: false,              
    },       
    address: {
        type: String, 
        required: false,                   
    },       
});

const importer_schema = mongoose.Schema({
        fullname: {
        type: String,
        required: true,          
    },   
    email: {
        type: String,  
        required: true,      
        //required: true,     
    },       
    phone: {
        type: String, 
        required: false,              
    },       
    address: {
        type: String, 
        required: false,                   
    },       
});

const freight_forwarder_schema = mongoose.Schema({

    fullname: {
        type: String,
        required: true,          
    },   
    email: {
        type: String,       
        required: false,     
    },       
    phone: {
        type: String, 
        required: false,              
    },       
    address: {
        type: String, 
        required: false,                   
    },       
});

const transporter_schema = mongoose.Schema({
    fullname: {
        type: String,
        required: true,             
    },   
    email: {
        type: String,        
        //required: true,     
    },       
    phone: {
        type: String, 
        //required: false,              
    },       
    address: {
        type: String, 
        required: false,                   
    },       
});

const consignment_details_info_schema = mongoose.Schema({
    container_no: {
        type: String,       
        required: true, 
    },       
    container_size: {
        type: String,
        required: true,     
        enum: ['20','40'],
    },       
    description_of_goods: {
        type: String, 
        required: false,              
    },       
    weight: {
        type: String, 
        required: false,              
    },       
    volume: {
        type: String, 
        required: false,              
    },                     
});

const cargo_details_schema = mongoose.Schema({    
    bill_of_lading: {
        type: String,
        required: true,  
        unique: true,        
    },   
    shipper_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,  
        //unique: true,        
    },       
    importer_id: {
        type: String,
        required: true,     
        //type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        //ref: 'AppStakeholder',
        //required: false,                 
    },       
    transporter_id: {
        type: String,
        required: true,     
        //type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        //ref: 'AppStakeholder',
        //required: false,                 
    },       
    freight_forwarder_id: {
        type: String,
        required: true,     
        //type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        //ref: 'AppStakeholder',
        //required: false,                 
    },       
    bonded_terminal_id: {
        type: String,
        required: true,     
        //type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        //ref: 'AppStakeholder',
        //required: false,                 
    },       
    consignee: importer_schema,
    bonded_terminal: bonded_terminal_schema,
    freight_forwarder: freight_forwarder_schema, 
    transporter: transporter_schema,
    consignment_details_info: [consignment_details_info_schema],       
});

const vesselSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
 {
    stakeholder_id:{
        type: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    },
    stakeholder:{
        type: String,        
        //type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        //ref: 'AppStakeholder',
        required: true,
    },
    vessel_code: {
        type: String,            
        required: true,
        unique: true,
    },       
    vessel_name: {
        type: String,            
        required: true,
    },
    voyage_number: {
        type: String,            
        required: true,
    },
    imo_number: {
        type: String,            
        required: true,
    },
    port_of_origin: {
        type: String,            
        required: true,
    },
    port_of_transshipment : {
        type: String,            
        //required: true,
    },        
    port_of_discharge: {
        type: String,            
        required: true,
    },
    port_of_destination: {
        type: String,            
        required: true,
    },
    eta_date: {
        type: Date,            
        required: true,
    },    
    etd_date: {
        type: Date,            
        required: true,
    },    
    cargo_details: [cargo_details_schema],        
 }, 
 {
    timestamps: true,
  },
);

const Vessels = mongoose.model('Vessel', vesselSchema);

module.exports = Vessels;


The returned result:
{
  "status": "success",
  "response": [
    {
      "_id": "674ef5cb3e56097ee686o5389",
      "vessel_code": "VS0008213",
      "vessel_name": "Lee Maraham Inc.",
      "voyage_number": "82911045453",
      "imo_number": "992742220195",
      "port_of_discharge": "Cijano Port",
      "port_of_destination": "Sample Port",
      "eta_date": "2024-11-29T00:00:00.000Z",
      "etd_date": "2024-12-28T00:00:00.000Z",
      "cargo_details": {
        "bill_of_lading": "289821730",
        "shipper_name": "Timothy Lee",
        "consignment_details_info": [
          {
            "container_no": "MSK-11147U760",
            "container_size": "40",
            "description_of_goods": "Automobile items",
            "weight": "2 Tons",
            "volume": "81mm"
          },
          {
            "container_no": "MSK-211247U763",
            "container_size": "40",
            "description_of_goods": "Automobile items",
            "weight": "2 Tons",
            "volume": "81mm"
          },
          {
            "container_no": "MSK-311247U766",
            "container_size": "40",
            "description_of_goods": "Automobile items",
            "weight": "2 Tons",
            "volume": "81mm"
          },
          {
            "container_no": "MSK-411247U769",
            "container_size": "40",
            "description_of_goods": "Automobile items",
            "weight": "2 Tons",
            "volume": "81mm"
          },
          {
            "container_no": "MSK-511247U727",
            "container_size": "40",
            "description_of_goods": "Automobile items",
            "weight": "2 Tons",
            "volume": "81mm"
          }
        ],
        "importer_id": "6750838a51d231d319665fz3"
      },
      "shippingLine": [],
      "freightForwarder": [],
      "transporter": []
    },
    {
      "_id": "674ef5cb3e56097ee689bcb2",
      "vessel_code": "VS0008213",
      "vessel_name": "Lee Maraham Inc.",
      "voyage_number": "82911045453",
      "imo_number": "992742220195",
      "port_of_discharge": "Cijano Port",
      "port_of_destination": "Tin Can Island Port",
      "eta_date": "2024-11-29T00:00:00.000Z",
      "etd_date": "2024-12-28T00:00:00.000Z",
      "cargo_details": {
        "bill_of_lading": "311886122",
        "shipper_name": "Stephanie Lomberdo",
        "consignee": {
          "fullname": "Bokku Bakery & Groceries"
        },
        "bonded_terminal": {
          "fullname": "Sifax II"
        },
        "freight_forwarder": {
          "fullname": "Clearance Logistics"
        },
        "transporter": {
          "fullname": "Safe Journey Ventures"
        },
        "consignment_details_info": [
          {
            "container_no": "MSK-10047U000",
            "container_size": "40",
            "description_of_goods": "Automobile items",
            "weight": "2 Tons",
            "volume": "81mm"
          },
          {
            "container_no": "MSK-291247U921",
            "container_size": "40",
            "description_of_goods": "Automobile items",
            "weight": "2 Tons",
            "volume": "81mm"
          },
          {
            "container_no": "MSK-344927U555",
            "container_size": "40",
            "description_of_goods": "Automobile items",
            "weight": "2 Tons",
            "volume": "81mm"
          },
          {
            "container_no": "MSK-440017U092",
            "container_size": "40",
            "description_of_goods": "Automobile items",
            "weight": "2 Tons",
            "volume": "81mm"
          },
          {
            "container_no": "MSK-809047U428",
            "container_size": "40",
            "description_of_goods": "Automobile items",
            "weight": "2 Tons",
            "volume": "81mm"
          }
        ],
        "importer_id": "6750838a51d231d319612ec7"
      },
      "shippingLine": [],
      "freightForwarder": [],
      "transporter": []
    },
    {
      "_id": "674ef5cb3e56097ee689bcb2",
      "vessel_code": "VS0008213",
      "vessel_name": "Lee Maraham Inc.",
      "voyage_number": "82911045453",
      "imo_number": "992742220195",
      "port_of_discharge": "Cijano Port",
      "port_of_destination": "Tin Can Island Port",
      "eta_date": "2024-11-29T00:00:00.000Z",
      "etd_date": "2024-12-28T00:00:00.000Z",
      "cargo_details": {
        "bill_of_lading": "299936122",
        "shipper_name": "Styllion Vibrant",
        "consignee": {
          "fullname": "Chicken Republic Fast Food"
        },
        "bonded_terminal": {
          "fullname": "Sifax II"
        },
        "freight_forwarder": {
          "fullname": "Clearance Logistics"
        },
        "transporter": {
          "fullname": "Safe Journey Ventures"
        },
        "consignment_details_info": [
          {
            "container_no": "MSK-88747U000",
            "container_size": "40",
            "description_of_goods": "Automobile items",
            "weight": "2 Tons",
            "volume": "81mm"
          },
          {
            "container_no": "MSK-789247U921",
            "container_size": "40",
            "description_of_goods": "Automobile items",
            "weight": "2 Tons",
            "volume": "81mm"
          },
          {
            "container_no": "MSK-320927U555",
            "container_size": "40",
            "description_of_goods": "Automobile items",
            "weight": "2 Tons",
            "volume": "81mm"
          },
          {
            "container_no": "MSK-76117U092",
            "container_size": "40",
            "description_of_goods": "Automobile items",
            "weight": "2 Tons",
            "volume": "81mm"
          },
          {
            "container_no": "MSK-190247U428",
            "container_size": "40",
            "description_of_goods": "Automobile items",
            "weight": "2 Tons",
            "volume": "81mm"
          }
        ],
        "importer_id": "6750838a51d231d319612ec7"
      },
      "shippingLine": [],
      "freightForwarder": [],
      "transporter": []
    },
    {
      "_id": "674ef9ab4d5f3d03edbf3506",
      "vessel_code": "VS0004081",
      "vessel_name": "Ocean Journey Inc.",
      "voyage_number": "11066345453",
      "imo_number": "993853860195",
      "port_of_discharge": "Maroon Jin Port",
      "port_of_destination": "Tin Can Island Port",
      "eta_date": "2024-10-15T00:00:00.000Z",
      "etd_date": "2024-12-24T00:00:00.000Z",
      "cargo_details": {
        "bill_of_lading": "883773970",
        "shipper_name": "Timothy Lee",
        "consignee": {
          "fullname": "CashNPick Supermarket"
        },
        "bonded_terminal": {
          "fullname": "Sifax II"
        },
        "freight_forwarder": {
          "fullname": "Clearance Logistics"
        },
        "transporter": {
          "fullname": "Safe Journey Ventures"
        },
        "consignment_details_info": [
          {
            "container_no": "MSK-11147U760",
            "container_size": "40",
            "description_of_goods": "Automobile items",
            "weight": "2 Tons",
            "volume": "81mm"
          },
          {
            "container_no": "MSK-211247U763",
            "container_size": "40",
            "description_of_goods": "Automobile items",
            "weight": "2 Tons",
            "volume": "81mm"
          },
          {
            "container_no": "MSK-311247U766",
            "container_size": "40",
            "description_of_goods": "Automobile items",
            "weight": "2 Tons",
            "volume": "81mm"
          },
          {
            "container_no": "MSK-411247U769",
            "container_size": "40",
            "description_of_goods": "Automobile items",
            "weight": "2 Tons",
            "volume": "81mm"
          },
          {
            "container_no": "MSK-511247U727",
            "container_size": "40",
            "description_of_goods": "Automobile items",
            "weight": "2 Tons",
            "volume": "81mm"
          }
        ],
        "importer_id": "6750838a51d231d319612ec7"
      },
      "shippingLine": [],
      "freightForwarder": [],
      "transporter": []
    },
    .....other documents go here    
}

I want to achieve four things,

I want to pull the user details (fullname and email) from the Users collection using the Model.Aggregate. The current Model.aggregate() is not fetching the referenced collection fields.

I want to filter the Model.find() by subdocument field. The query worked but it is returning the full document by ignoring the subdocument field filtered by.

I want to count the total items in the subdocument array object "cargo_details.consignment_details_info" for different user(cargo_details.importer_id) because this will be different users(cargo_details.importer_id). So that I can count how many cargoes by each of them.



I want to count total items in the  cargo_details.consignment_details_info array object by each Vessel without filtering by subdocument field either using Model.find() or Model.Aggregate().

This query worked and fetched the reference collection field but didn't filter the records by subdocument field.
const importerCargoes = await Vessel.findOne(
        { 
       $and:[
       {'_id': '674ed7fd61f952ddf3e4a661'}, 

    {cargo_details: { $elemMatch: { importer_id: '6750838a51d231d319664uh4'}}}
    ] },       
  )   
  .select('vessel_code vessel_name voyage_number imo_number port_of_discharge port_of_transhipment port_of_destination eta_date etd_date cargo_details.bill_of_lading cargo_details.shipper_name cargo_details.consignment_details_info.container_no cargo_details.consignment_details_info.container_size cargo_details.consignment_details_info.description_of_goods cargo_details.consignment_details_info.volume cargo_details.consignment_details_info.weight')
  .populate({
    path: 'stakeholder',
    model: 'User',
    select: '-_id fullname',
    foreignField: '_id',
  });

This Model.aggregate worked fine and filtered the records by subdocument, but it didn't fetch the $lookup collection fields that was referenced
Vessel.aggregate([
      //{ $match : { '_id' : '674ed7fd61f952ddf3e4a661' } },
      { $unwind: "$cargo_details" },
      { $unwind: "$cargo_details.importer_id" },
        { $match : 
          { $or: [ 
            { 'cargo_details.importer_id' : '6750838a51d231d319664ds2' },
            { 'cargo_details.bonded_terminal_id' : '6750838a51d231d319664ds2' },
            { 'cargo_details.transporter_id' : '6750838a51d231d319664ds2' },
            { 'cargo_details.freight_forwarder_id' : '6750838a51d231d319664ds2' },
          ]
        } 
      },
        { $sort : {etd_date: -1} },
        
        {
          "$lookup": {
              "from": "users",
              "localField": "stakeholder",
              "foreignField": "_id",
              "as": "shippingLine"
          }
      },
        {
          "$lookup": {
              "from": "users",
              "localField": "cargo_details.freight_forwarder_id",
              "foreignField": "_id",
              "as": "freightForwarder"
          }
      },
        {
          "$lookup": {
              "from": "users",
              "localField": "cargo_details.transporter_id",
              "foreignField": "_id",
              "as": "transporter"
          }
      },
      {   $project: {       
        vessel_code: 1,
        vessel_name: 1,
        voyage_number: 1,
        imo_number: 1,
        port_of_discharge: 1,
        port_of_transhipment: 1,
        port_of_destination: 1,
        eta_date: 1,
        etd_date: 1,        
       'cargo_details.bill_of_lading': 1,
       'cargo_details.shipper_name': 1,
       'cargo_details.importer_id': 1,
       'cargo_details.consignee.fullname': 1,
       'cargo_details.bonded_terminal.fullname': 1,
       'cargo_details.freight_forwarder.fullname': 1,
       'cargo_details.transporter.fullname': 1,
       'cargo_details.consignment_details_info.container_no': 1,
       'cargo_details.consignment_details_info.container_size': 1,
       'cargo_details.consignment_details_info.description_of_goods': 1,
       'cargo_details.consignment_details_info.weight': 1,
       'cargo_details.consignment_details_info.volume': 1,
        shippingLine: { fullname: 1, email: 1, phone: 1 },
        transporter: { fullname: 1, email: 1, phone: 1 },
        freightForwarder: { fullname: 1, email: 1, phone: 1 }
        }
    }
  
    ])
    .then(response => {

      res.status(200).json({
        status: 'success',         
          importedCargoes
          response      
      });     
    })
    .catch(error => {
        res.json({
            message: `An error occured!: ${error}`
        })
    })


Can you please provide some sample data?

Maybe this motorDriver: { fullname: "$motorDriver.fullname", email: "$motorDriver.email" }

@Wernfried Domscheit Thank you for the respond.  changed referenced field to the solution you provided but didn't work too. It still doesn't fetch the fullname and email fields from the referenced users collection. Same query returned result from the Motor collection but didn't linke the referenced users collection fullname and email fields, they are null.

garrage_of_origin_user is of type String whereas the _id in the users collection will be of type ObjectId. That is a type mismatch so the $lookup won't match them. Mongoose does a lot of type casting during queries but not during the $lookup. There are plenty of workarounds but the best advice is to address the problem in your schema and change garrage_of_origin_user to an ObjectId even if that means you have to go back and update all the data from scratch again.

Hi @RaulHernandez: The problem you're experiencing stems from the mismatch in field types, incorrect $lookup configuration, and how you're referencing nested subdocuments.  I try to help in the 1st answer

I understood, I have changed it from the schema and it still didn't fetch the reference fields from the users collection. It is fetching records but the lookup fields reference are empty. I hope you are away I am using match and unwind as it was in the original question and again, why did the query worked with Model.find().populate() even when the reference fields were in String but not ObjectID? Mongoose Aggregate is the best option for me because I will use count on subdocuments but it is not satisfying the lookup fields.

Again, please provide a few sample documents.

@Wernfried Domscheit, i have dited the question to be more comprehensive. You can look into it. Thank you for your concern and following up.

Once more: please provide some sample input data!

@WernfriedDomscheit, Thank you for following up. That is the sample data, please check the question again because I have edited/updated the question. The respond data and the schema are there which are enough I think and again, you find record by either the document _id field or subdocument field just as I have done in my sample code that I provided. And you may find a record of a specific document field _id along with subdocument field.

This is a COMPLETELY different schema than it was originally! Please open a new question for it.

Some general weak points with your model: Why do you create 4 identical models? Numeric values (like volume or weight) should be stored as numbers, not strings. For shipping containers the "volume" is redundant when you have the container type (20 or 40 feet)

To us programmers it is redundant but to layman that uses the information, they need to see it and there for their use and some clarity and because no computation is going to be perform on the field, hence they are stored as string. The schema is the original schema i'm working on, I just used the previous as an example to the new schema hoping i would solve this once i got solution for the previous one.

Those identical schemas that act as subdocuments are not important because the bearers will be pulled from different collection(user). They might not initially have _id user collection before they get into the vessel model. If I open a new question for this, you might not see the question again

@WernfriedDomscheit I opened a new thread for the post and this is the url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79315185/lookup-field-empty-from-referenced-collection-field-in-result-response . Thank you

Solution:
Step 1: update the schema to use Schema.Types.ObjectId for these fields:
garrage_of_origin_user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
},
sub_garrage_user1: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
},
sub_garrage_user2: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
},

Then ensure that you're saving valid ObjectId values in these fields.

Step 2: you should fix the incorrect $lookup for Subdocuments
To pull data for sub_garrage_user1 and sub_garrage_user2, you need separate $lookup stages for each field because $lookup works at the document level, not the nested subdocument level.

Step 3: In your $project stage, you need to properly project the nested fields to include the results of $lookup.


Correct aggregation query:
Motors.aggregate([
    // $lookup for garrage_of_origin_user
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            localField: "garrage_of_origin_user",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "garrageUserDetails",
        },
    },
    // $lookup for sub_garrage_user1
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            localField: "sub_origin_garage.sub_garrage_user1",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "subGarrageUser1Details",
        },
    },
    // $lookup for sub_garrage_user2
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            localField: "sub_origin_garage.sub_garrage_user2",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "subGarrageUser2Details",
        },
    },
    // Project the required fields
    {
        $project: {
            motor_code: 1,
            motor_name: 1,
            motor_number: 1,
            imo_number: 1,
            garrage_of_origin: 1,
            journey_date: 1,
            "sub_origin_garage.garrage_name1": 1,
            "sub_origin_garage.garrage_name2": 1,
            garrageUserDetails: {
                fullname: 1,
                email: 1,
            },
            subGarrageUser1Details: {
                fullname: 1,
                email: 1,
            },
            subGarrageUser2Details: {
                fullname: 1,
                email: 1,
            },
        },
    },
])
    .then((response) => {
        res.status(200).json({
            status: "success",
            response,
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        res.json({
            message: `An error occurred: ${error}`,
        });
    });


Thank you for your kind respond and I respect your skill . If I use Model.find().populate() even as the garrage_of_origin_user is type String, Model.find().populate does include the Users collection field and fetch the fullname and email field even when the field is not ObjectID. I changed those fields to Object ID and make it ref the User collection as you have explained but it did not pull the fullname and email from the User collection again. It still didn't work. It returns empty  for the lookup fields but other fields of the document are there except for fullname and email.

hello @RaulHernandez: The issue you're describing indicates that the populate functionality of Mongoose is not correctly linking the referenced fields to the Users collection, even after updating the schema to use ObjectId with a ref. This suggests either a configuration issue or a problem with how data is stored or queried.
both should be investigated.

I suggest few steps ... I know it is frustrating ...
If .populate() works with String but not ObjectId:
(1) Verify that the data in the Motors collection contains valid ObjectId values that match entries in the Users collection.
(2) Ensure that the ref and model name for Users match exactly.
(3) Use .populate() correctly for nested fields.
(4) Debug with mongoose.set('debug', true) to check the actual MongoDB queries.

i appreciate your response. I will be glad if you can help me with how to filter by nested subdocument using Model.find() because with Model.find() i am getting correct result with populating but just that the .find() would return all records but not filter by nested subdocument no matter what and that is the main reason why I moved to Model.aggregate. The fields use to do the ref are valid objectId because I use mongoose.isValidObjectId() to check if the string is valid MongoDB Object Id before I use it for the query. It might be that the aggregate query is not build correctly

Ali Saberi I am 100% sure the problem is not the that field used is String type because if Model.find() treats the field correctly and use it to query data with .find() then mongoose treats it well and besides, I check first with mongoose.isValidObjectId() if it is valid Object Id before I pass it to the query. There are many things the Model.aggregate() can do that i think .find can do because I want to count the nested subdocument and grouped by subdocument field too. I think something is not right in the $lookup. I am an SQL guy that migrated to NoSQL

Three $lookup for such a simple query, that's quite a lot. You should review your data model. Maybe have a look at Building with Patterns: A Summary

@Wernfried Domscheit Thank you for your time.
The point is, the $lookup isn't even bringing the fields in the referenced collection, it showed empty. But if the data modeling worked correctly for Model.find() and returned correct data, why would Model.aggregate() be different. Reason why I am using aggregate is because Model.find() isn't filtering the query by subdocument field and it is returning all the records which is not what I wanted. Model.find() correctly fetch the fields of the populated referenced collection. So why is Model.aggregate() different?

@wernfried-domscheit, please can you give me a comprehensive tutorial that I can with Model.find() to filter MongoDB records by subdocuments fields. I have used different query but it would return all documents without effecting the filtering by the subdocument fields. I am interested in the Model.aggregate() because i will need to do many data analysis from the collection documents overtime.
